# Washing machine - Will not agitate

Tags: clothes-washer, washer

I have an Electrolux (Frigidaire) stacked washer/dryer combo that is not agitating. The control circuity, lid latch, motor, and belt all seem to work. It fills, drains, spins, and with the lid open at the agitate cycle, and the switch manually engaged, the motor spins. Grasping at straws, I pulled the agitator itself off, and the "drive block" (spline gear) which is lose enough to turn does not turn.

I note that the transmission itself is stationary while the washer is in agitate cycle, but is free to and actually spins itself while in the spin/drain cycle.

It isn't clear at all how the transmission is signaled to engage the drive block, vs spinning the tub.

Is there any more reasonable steps I can take to diagnose and repair?

For clarity, my machine is an Electrolux mex731cfs1

Answer (score -1):

Here's the [Sears Help](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/universal-multiflex-frigidaire/washer-dryer-combo/model-MEX731CFS1-repair/0152000/laundry-center-repair/symptom/lc02616.html) for your washer if it "Won’t agitate or spin."

It says it could be:

- The lid lock switch
- The washer drive motor
- The washer timer

They also have blown-up diagrams of each assembly.  You can buy the replacement parts there.  (Or get the part number and search online.)

You can find the wiring diagram and user manual (not the repair manual) [here.](http://www.youserguide.com/wiki/Universal_MEX731CF)

Here is the [service manual](http://www.allrepairmanuals.com/universal-multiflex-washer-dryer-combo.htm?model_number=MEX731CFS1&manual_type=SERVICE).  It is $9.95.  I haven't verified the helpfulness of this.

Comment: I specifically described how those three top options were not the problem in my specific case.

Comment: You asked how to "diagnose and repair" your specific model of washing machine.  I found the service manual for you.  You said you didn't know how the transmission was signaled and I found the wiring diagram for you.  Sorry my research wasn't good enough for you.  Hopefully it could help someone else.